# Trouble with preg_replace() in Foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, preg-replace, domdocument

Long story short, my client lost access to their server because of a dispute,   and they need all their club photos so I can build them a new site. I'm having to download them by URL, and they are handled by a PHP output that gives different sizes to reduce server load.

There are over 3000 of them, and I'm not about to waste time doing this one by one.

So, I decided to write a quick and [very] dirty PHP script that will crawl the pages using `DOMDocument` looking for the links to the image, across each album and then across the album sub-pages.

Everything works fine, except this one particular part of the script that looks on the album page for:

(1) a link to an image, which is

```
<div class='imagethumb'>
    <a href="/gallery/index.php?album=blowout1&image=blahblah.jpg" title="Blahblah>
        <img src="/gallery/index.php?album=blowout1&image=blahblah_thumb.jpg />
    </a>
</div>
```

(2) a link to a subsequent page, which is

```
<li>
    <a href="/gallery/index.php?album=beginning&amp;page=2" title="Page 2">2</a>
</li>
```

(3) a link to the album "Last Page" or "..."

```
<li>
    <a href="/gallery/index.php?album=recognition&page=9" title="Page 9">...</a>
</li>
```

Here's the relevant part of the script:

```
//$url is an argument in the function wrapping this script

//look on albums for links
foreach ($album_links as $a_url) {
    $album_html = file_get_contents($a_url['url']);
    $album = new DOMDocument;
    $album->loadHTML($album_html);
    $i_links = $album->getElementsByTagName('a');
    $album_title = $album->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->textContent;

    //to keep track of the number of sub-page links found, exclude page 1
    $num_page_lnks = 1;

    //search through all links on the page, look for:
    foreach ($i_links as $link) {

        //Links contained in div with class='imagethumb'
        if ($link->parentNode->getAttribute('class') == 'imagethumb' ) {
            array_push($image_links, ["album" => str_replace(" | ", "", $album_title), "title" => $link->getAttribute('title'), "url" => "http://" . parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST) . $link->getAttribute('href') . "&p=*full-image"]);
        }

        //links contained in li with no class, has a page number in the title, and is not a "..." link
        elseif ($link->parentNode->getAttribute('class') == '' && preg_match('/Page\040\d*/', $link->getAttribute('title')) && $link->textContent != "...") {
            //add to the number of sub page links found
            $num_page_lnks++;
            array_push($image_page_links,  "http://" . parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST) . $link->getAttribute('href'));
        }

        //links containing the text "..." (link to last album page, if more than 7 pages)
        elseif($link->textContent == "...") {

            //Parse the url into parts
            $url_parse=[];
            parse_str($link->getAttribute('href'), $url_parse);

            //Last Page links appear when greater than 7 pages, so start at 8 ($num_page_links + 1)
            for ($count = ($num_page_lnks + 1); $count < ($url_parse['page'] + 1); $count++) {
                array_push($image_page_links,  "http://" . parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST) . preg_replace("/[^\=]\d+$/", $count, $link->getAttribute('href')));
            }
        }
    }
    unset($album);
    unset($album_html);
    unset($i_links);
}
```

In the event that the script finds a sub-page link, it adds to `$num_page_links`, so that when it finds a `"..."` link, it will know where to start when creating the in-between page links

And here's what that returns:

```
{
    "0": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=beginning&page=2",
    "1": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=beginning&page=3",
    "2": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=history&page=2",
    "3": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=history&page=3",
    "4": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=history&page=4",
    "5": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=history&page=5",
    "6": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=history&page=6",
    "7": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=history&page=7",
    "8": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=memorial&page=2",
    "9": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=memorial&page=3",
    "10": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=memorial&page=4",
    "11": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=memorial&page=5",
    "12": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=memorial&page=6",
    "13": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=memorial&page=7",
    "14": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=memorial&page=9",
    "15": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=memorial&page=9",
    "16": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=members&page=2",
    "17": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=members&page=3",
    "18": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=members&page=4",
    "19": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=members&page=5",
    "20": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=members&page=6",
    "21": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=members&page=7",
    "22": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=members&page=8",
    "23": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=members&page=9",
    "24": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=members&page=10",
    "25": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=members&page=11",
    "26": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=toy_run&page=2",
    "27": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=toy_run&page=3",
    "28": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=toy_run&page=4",
    "29": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=toy_run&page=5",
    "30": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=toy_run&page=6",
    "31": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=toy_run&page=7",
    "32": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=toy_run&page=8",
    "33": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=recognition&page=2",
    "34": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=recognition&page=3",
    "35": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=recognition&page=4",
    "36": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=recognition&page=5",
    "37": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=recognition&page=6",
    "38": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=recognition&page=7",
    "39": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=recognition&page=9",
    "40": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=recognition&page=9",
    "41": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=blowout1&page=2",
    "42": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=blowout1&page=3",
    "43": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=blowout1&page=4",
    "44": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=blowout1&page=5",
    "45": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=blowout1&page=6",
    "46": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=blowout1&page=7",
    "47": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=blowout1&page=8",
    "48": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=blowout1&page=9",
    "49": "http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=blowout1&page=10"
}
```

That's exactly the right amount of sub-pages to have in that object, but the problem is this:

1. When there's 7 or less album pages (6 sub-pages) the script works great
2. When there's 8 album pages (7 sub-pages) the script works fine
3. When there's 9 album pages (8 sub-pages - [1] Current page, [2][3][4][5][6][7][...] Last Page (9)), the script doubles Page 9
4. When there's 10 or more album pages, no problems.

I can't figure out what I did wrong.

Edit:

Here's the source HTML code of `$i_links`:

```
<ul class="pagelist">
    <li class="prev"><span class="disabledlink">« prev</span></li>
    <li class="current"><a href="/gallery/index.php?album=recognition" title="Page 1 (Current Page)">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/gallery/index.php?album=recognition&amp;page=2" title="Page 2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/gallery/index.php?album=recognition&amp;page=3" title="Page 3">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="/gallery/index.php?album=recognition&amp;page=4" title="Page 4">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="/gallery/index.php?album=recognition&amp;page=5" title="Page 5">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="/gallery/index.php?album=recognition&amp;page=6" title="Page 6">6</a></li>
    <li><a href="/gallery/index.php?album=recognition&amp;page=7" title="Page 7">7</a></li>
   <li><a href="/gallery/index.php?album=recognition&amp;page=9" title="Page 9">...</a></li>
    <li class="next"><a href="/gallery/index.php?album=recognition&amp;page=2" title="Next Page">next »</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your last nested loop:

```
//Last Page links appear when greater than 7 pages, so start at 8 ($num_page_links + 1)
for ($count = ($num_page_lnks + 1); $count < ($url_parse['page'] + 1); $count++) {
     array_push($image_page_links,  "http://" . parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST) . preg_replace("/[^\=]\d+$/", $count, $link->getAttribute('href')));
 }
```

When you are reaching the 7th sublink (with text content "...") the `$num_page_lnks` variable has value `7` and `$url_parse['page']` has value `9`. So there will be two iterations where `$count` variable will be assigned with `8`, then - with `9`.
But ... those links remains the same:

```
"http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=recognition&page=9"
"http://club.website.com/gallery/index.php?album=recognition&page=9"
```

because your regex pattern doesn't make the expected replacement.

```
var_dump(preg_replace("/[^\=]\d+$/",8,"/gallery/index.php?album=recognition&amp;page=9"));
// will output:
string(47) "/gallery/index.php?album=recognition&page=9"
```

Change your regex pattern to this one: `/\d+$/` or consider some other logic.

Comment: Curious....If it's not matching properly, then why is it working on the other albums with more than 9 pages...

Comment: Whatever the reason it's not matching in that one single case, that simple regex change fixed it! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Dexter, you are welcome. (Perhaps, the other albums don't contain link with text content `"..."`)